# Hierarchy principle: who defined it first?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, terminology, history, main-effects

Different questions here deal with the problem of whether to include main effects in interaction models, for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189218/why-include-insignificant-main-term-when-interaction-term-is-included), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27724/do-all-interactions-terms-need-their-individual-terms-in-regression-model) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/including-the-interaction-but-not-the-main-effects-in-a-model) (for the opposite problem, omitting interaction coefficients where there are interaction effects in the DGP, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629016/model-without-interaction-terms-how-wrong-is-it)).

But I have found that the general suggestion to include the main terms in interaction models is called "Hierarchy principle", for example [here](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Eane/st572/notes/lec08.pdf), or "hierarchical principle", for example [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/164-interaction-effect-in-multiple-regression-essentials/).

Is there a reference for this name of the principle? Who called this principle with this name? What's the first use of this name for this principle?

Comment: Another term for this is [principle of marginality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality), I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about "hierarchical", but this is also called the "marginality" principle, (see [for example](https://doi.org/10.1002/bimj.202300069)), which goes back at least to [Nelder 1977](https://doi.org/10.2307/2344517).